# Crash while filling a 16bpp image with -O3 optimization and odd pitch

Tags: c++, optimization, g++

I have written a very simple code to fill a 32x32 16bpp image with a constant value (1024). The image buffer is hosted by a `std::vector`. The **pitch/stride** of my image (i.e. the number of bytes between two successive lines) is large enough to hold an entire line, but is **set an odd number**. Here is my code:

```c
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
  int width = 32;
  int height = 32;
  int pitch = width * 2 + 1;

  std::vector<uint8_t> image(height * pitch);
  uint8_t* buffer = &image[0];

  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
  {
    uint16_t* p = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(buffer + y * pitch);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++, p++)
    {
      *p = 1024;
    }
  }
}
```

I am using Linux x86_64 with gcc 4.6.1 (Ubuntu 11.10). The code runs fine with the `-O0`, `-O1` and `-O2` optimization levels. Valgrind does not report any access violation. However, as soon as I switch to `-O3` or use the **`-ftree-vectorize` option for auto-vectorization**, the program crashes:

```
# g++ -g -O3 ./test.cpp -Wall -pedantic && ./a.out
Segmentation fault

# g++ -g -O2 -ftree-vectorize ./test.cpp -Wall -pedantic && ./a.out
Segmentation fault
```

Neither gdb nor valgrind provide any helpful information:

```
# valgrind ./a.out
==3840== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3840== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3840== Using Valgrind-3.6.1-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3840== Command: ./a.out
==3840== 
==3840== 
==3840== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3840==  General Protection Fault
==3840==    at 0x4005B3: main (test.cpp:18)
==3840== 
==3840== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3840==     in use at exit: 2,080 bytes in 1 blocks
==3840==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 2,080 bytes allocated
==3840== 
==3840== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3840==    definitely lost: 2,080 bytes in 1 blocks
==3840==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3840==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3840==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3840==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3840== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3840== 
==3840== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3840== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
Segmentation fault
```

The crash does not happen when I switch to 32bit binaries with the `-m32` gcc flag. It does not occur either if I use an even pitch (e.g. `pitch = width * 2 + 2`). Could anyone help me to spot the (certainly stupid) error I make in my code? Many thanks in advance!

---

**UPDATE:** As suggested by Jonathan, I have just reported this problem to the GCC developers:
http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56392

Comment: Your calculation of pitch looks unusual.  Do you mean to set it to an odd value n (well, an odd number of uint16_t elements)?  Its more common to see it being rounded up to a multiple of 4 or 8.

Comment: Yes, it is purposely set to an odd number. The crash does not occur with even pitch... and I am not able to figure out why by myself :)

Comment: Compare the generated assembly code. Also, you might want to test with the individual options `-O3` turns on to see which one is the culprit (See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options for a list of the options).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The culprit is the `-ftree-vectorize` option. Unfortunately, I am not familiar enough with assembly to understand the reason for the crash.

Comment: @BoBTFish It also crashes with g++ 4.4.6 and g++ 4.5.4. The problem clearly comes from gcc auto-vectorization.

Comment: Then you could try with the `-O3` flag, but disable the vectorization optimization with `-fno-tree-vectorize`.

Comment: It's a problem with alignment of the `uint16_t`. Please report it to http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla (replacing the `std::vector` with `uint8_t* image = new uint8_t[height * pitch]();`)

Comment: Yes, but is my code illegal for some reason or is it a bug inside gcc that should be reported?

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks, I will submit a bug report. FYI, the crash does not occur if I use `malloc` instead of the `new[]` operator. This is clearly a C++-related problem.

Comment: @Jonathan The code accesses a misaligned uint16_t. Is that not UB anyway?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: sorry for the misunderstanding, my answer about the bug report was addressed to Joachim ;)

Comment: @jmetcalfe, I think the vectorizer is supposed to handle misaligned accesses on platforms that support them, which I think includes x86_64.  It might still be an aliasing violation, but `-fno-strict-aliasing` doesn't change anything. I might be wrong, but asking on the gcc-help list or reporting a (possibly invalid) bug seems appropriate to me

Comment: Well that got a quick response, UB as @jmetcalfe said

Answer (score 4):

My question has been answered by Richard Blener on the [gcc Bugzilla](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56392):

> "You are dereferencing a pointer to uint16_t that is not sufficiently aligned for that type.  The C standard prohibits this, resulting in undefined behavior."

In my opinion, a warning should however be generated about this undefined behavior. Please also note that this explanation was also given by @jmetcalfe in the comments to this post.

Comment: The `reinterpret_cast` is your way of telling the compiler to shut up and just juggle the pointers. There are so many virtually undetectable scenarios involving reinterpret_cast that trying to write warnings for them is futile.

Comment: @Tisys, do not confuse undefined and unspecified, they're very different